# A string Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the alphabet $X$={$C,D,S,T,X,Z$}

A) how many strings of length 17 over the alphabet $X$ contain 4 $C's$, 2 $T's$, 8 $X's$ and $3 Z's$?

B) How many of these strings in part A) have all 4 $C's$ before the 2 $T's$?

Comment: i know that the number of strings with that combination are 17!/(4!2!8!3!) but i don;'t know where to begin with figuring out to determine the strings with 4 C's in front of the T's.

Comment: the only way i KNOW to show is the number of strings with the C's in the first four or the T's in last 2 spaces... but that won't help me with this....

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You say you have the answer to $A$.  Then for $B$, just look at the $C$s and $T$s.  The only acceptable order for them is $CCCCTT$.  How many orders were there for them in part $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing down the $C$'s and $T$'s, leaving some gaps in between them:
$$
\_\_~C~\_\_~C~\_\_~C~\_\_~C~\_\_~T~\_\_~T~\_\_
$$
We must now use the remaining $8$ $X$'s and $3$ $Z$'s to fill the $7$ remaining gaps. To do this, we modify [our usual stars-and-bars approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to this type of problem. Observe that we can encode any valid string as a string of $8$ $X$'s and $3$ $Z$'s and $6$ bars. For example, the valid string:
$$
\underline{}C\underline{XX}C\underline{XZZX}C\underline{}C\underline{}T\underline{Z}T\underline{XXXX}
$$
can be encoded as:
$$
\mid XX \mid XZZX \mid ~ \mid ~ \mid Z \mid XXXX
$$
Hence, it suffices to count the number of possible strings that can be formed using $8$ $X$'s and $3$ $Z$'s and $6$ bars. Using our approach from part (a), we obtain:
$$
\frac{17!}{8!3!6!}
$$